# convert dataframe in python from single row to multi rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

I have the following df in python :
[image]

and i want to convert it into this :

[image]

and I kind stuck on how to do this is python via df , any help please :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# wide to long + minor cosmetic manipulation
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df=df, stubnames=['sensor'], i=['timestamp','event_id'], 
                       j='sensor_log', sep='_')
       .rename(columns={'sensor':'sensor_val'})
       .reset_index()
       )

out

    timestamp  event_id  sensor_log  sensor_val
0           5         1           1    0.548814
1           5         1           2    0.602763
2           5         1           3    0.423655
3           5         1           4    0.437587
4           5         1           5    0.963663
5           5         1           6    0.791725
6           5         1           7    0.568045
7           5         1           8    0.071036
8           9         2           1    0.715189
9           9         2           2    0.544883
10          9         2           3    0.645894
11          9         2           4    0.891773
12          9         2           5    0.383442
13          9         2           6    0.528895
14          9         2           7    0.925597
15          9         2           8    0.087129
```

**Used `df`**

```
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

# setup
data = {f'sensor_{k+1}': v for k, v in enumerate(np.random.random((8,2)))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).assign(timestamp=[5,9], event_id=[1,2])
```

**Explanation**

- Use `pd.wide_to_long` with:

  - `stubnames` storing the recurring prefix(es) in the columns to be transformed, i.e. `'sensor'`;
  - `i` storing the columns to be used as `id` variable, i.e. `'timestamp'` and `'event_id'`;
  - `j` storing the name for the column that hold the suffixes, i.e. 'sensor' `1, 2, 3, etc.`;
  - `sep` with the separator between stubname and suffixes. (Technically, you could just skip it, and use `'sensor_'`, if you are going to rename that column anyway.
- Chain [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to change `'sensor'` to `'sensor_val'` and finally, reset the index using [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use `melt` function for this. And add some formatting to the result columns:

```
new_df = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=["timestamp", "eventId"],
    value_name="sensor_val",
    var_name="sensor"
)
new_df["sensor"] = new_df["sensor"].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    timestamp  eventId  sensor  sensor_val
0           5        1       1    0.358708
1           9        2       1    0.414703
2           5        1       2    0.146218
3           9        2       2    0.076579
4           5        1       3    0.111423
5           9        2       3    0.031616
6           5        1       4    0.425724
7           9        2       4    0.512726
8           5        1       5    0.967760
9           9        2       5    0.333880
10          5        1       6    0.977313
11          9        2       6    0.003731
12          5        1       7    0.030092
13          9        2       7    0.086239
14          5        1       8    0.583323
15          9        2       8    0.927643
```

(I've created a mock dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [5, 9],
    "eventId": [1, 2]
})

for i in range(1, 9):
    df["sensor_{}".format(i)] = np.random.random(size=(2,))
```

but you should really add an input dataset in form of code rather than a picture to make answering simpler.)

Comment: Nice solution as well. Basically, what [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is doing under the hood, I think (see `Notes` in the docs). Note that [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) allows you to add custom names for the `variable` and `value` column in the result. So conveniently, instead of adding `.rename(..., axis=1)`, you can also write: `pd.melt(df, id_vars=["timestamp", "eventId"], value_name='sensor_val', var_name='sensor')`.

Comment: Good point! I've edited my answer and will use this from now on :)